# Does MongoDB work on iOS?

Tags: ios, mongodb, mobile, ios4

Has MongoDB ever been compiled to work on iOS devices?  I know the terms of the App Store do not allow an application to launch a subprocess, so the `DBDirectClient` class would have to be used to access the data files in-process.

Any thoughts?

Comment: similar question (includes this one): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211041/mongodb-for-c-and-iphone-app

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but the question that you linked to does not address that ability to use MongoDB as an embedded database, only as a server process which is not allowed on iOS. The `DBDirectClient` class mentioned above is used by several of the command line tools included with MongoDB. It allows the tools to directly manipulate the data store when the server process is not running.  So, back to the original question:  Has anyone been able to compile and use MongoDB on iOS?

Comment: We've used CouchBase mobile here and I would not recommend it. It is now dead and replaced by TouchDB which appears to be 1000% better.

Answer (score 1):

While there is an Objective-C driver for Mongo: https://github.com/timburks/NuMongoDB, nobody has yet compiled an iOS embeddable version of it.  Here are the official list of supported versions: http://www.mongodb.org/downloads

Answer (score 1):

http://www.10gen.com/presentations/mongosv2010/ios

only for answering purposes, since this thread is a bit old ;)